# Access doctrine from authentication failure handler in Symfony2

Tags: authentication, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to write some loggin failure info in database from a custom authentication handler.
My problem is to gain access to the database since I don't know where the Doctrine object might be stored

Here's my code for now :

```
namespace MyApp\FrontBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse as RedirectResponse;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication as Auth;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException as AuthException;

class SecurityHandler implements Auth\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthException $token)
    {
        try
        {
            $lastLoginFailure = new DateTime();

            // get database object here
        }
        catch(\Exception $ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi titiyoyo, Do you got answer? is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your SecurityHandler into a service and then inject the doctrine entity manager into it.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 3):

1. Start command php app/console container:debug.
2. Copy `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` and paste to your hadler constructor arguments like
   [...., @doctrine.orm.entity_manager].
3. In hadler use `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should extends your class "SecurityHandler" with ContainerAware if you want to use service since your Security Handler is not a controller.

```
class SecurityHandler extend ContainerAware implements Auth\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthException $token)
    {
        try
        {
        $lastLoginFailure = new DateTime();

        // get database object here
        $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
        $repository = $doctrine->getRepository('*NAME OF REPO*');
        }
        catch(\Exception $ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope.  Not only is providing access to the container a bad idea but you didn't show how the container actually gets into the handler.

Comment: I will not code for him, he can make a little search on the ContainerAware and see that the set container method can do it for him.
Create a service only for one method, it's a lot of code for simply access to doctrine.

Comment: @Ahwebdev i never asked for you to code this for me anyway, but just hinting me up on it, so why are you putting this up ? Also, I did make my own research on that topic and am experimenting on it at the moment.

Comment: He only brought it up because I down voted his answer. In S2 understanding services and injections is key.

Comment: as well, for reference, after reading [the official doc about services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html), I found [this page](http://www.martinsikora.com/symfony2-and-dependency-injection) to be very helpful

Comment: @Cerad i agree with you, I am not a king of sf2 services, I use it when i really need it. But code a service just to access the container and just for that handler is sometimes very long.
And Just for info and progress is SF2, Why it's not a good way to add the containerAware in the hanlder ? Maybe i forgot some rules ? thanks

Comment: @titiyo, I am sorry if my answer was not helping you. i know you do not need it, i answer to put you on a way of search.